# tengo esta excepcon testng: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoReuseaddr

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, test-ng

que debo hacer para que no me salga esta excepción cuando trato de correr mis pruebas en selenium con testNG.

> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class
>   TestCaseJuntos.BeforeandAfterclass    at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
>     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:166)     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:26)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:114)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoReuseaddr(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getHttpParams(HttpClientFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:52)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:81)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:81)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
>     at
>   TestCaseJuntos.BeforeandAfterclass.(BeforeandAfterclass.java:23)
>     ... 26 more

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` indica que el programa fue compilado haciendo una llamada a un método de una clase, pero durante la ejecución el JVM detecta que la clase de ese nombre que encuentra no tiene ése método.

La causa más común es que estés poniendo una versión errónea (normalmente más antigua) de la clase llamada en el classpath.

Buscando el [Javadoc de `HttpConnectionParams`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html), aparece un método `setSoReuseAddr()`; viendo su información vemos que:

a) está `Deprecated`.

b) existe desde la versión 4.1 de la librería.

Por la parte de `Deprecated` no hay mucho que hacer, sólo esperar que salga una nueva versión de la librería que llama al método y que use el método correcto. Por la otra parte, queda claro que tienes que asegurarte que usas una versión de la librería `HttpComponents` de Apache que sea 4.1 o superior.